# Optimize the code to sum scores for the tokens in noun phrase list

Tags: python, list

**Requirement**

- The below code looks complicated in time complexity, I am looking for solutions to optimize the below code.

Aim of the below code is to sum up the scores of tokens if the token is in nounphrase_list and also all_tokens (detailed explanation below)

```
full_string = ["Mitchell is using machine learning and software engineering on his mobile phone to generate songs . On top of machine learning he is also using deep learning"

# the token list are words from above full_string
all_tokens = ["Mitchell", "is", "using", "machine", "learning", 
              "and", "software", "engineering", "on", "his", 
              "mobile", "phone", "to", "generate", "songs", 
              "On", "top", "of", "machine", "learning", 
              "he", "is", "also", "using", "deep", "learning"]

all_scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]

# These noun phrases extracted from the full_string
nounphrase_list = ["Mitchell", "machine learning", "software engineering", "machine learning", "deep learning"]

updated_scores = all_scores.copy()

seen_indices = set()
for np_item in nounphrase_list:
    np_words = np_item.split()
    indices = []
    for word in np_words:
        for idx, token in enumerate(all_tokens):
            if word == token:
                if idx not in seen_indices:
                    indices.append(idx)
                    seen_indices.add(idx)
                    break
    sum_score = sum(all_scores[idx] for idx in indices)
    for idx in indices:
        updated_scores[idx] = sum_score
```

**Explanation**:

- `Mitchell` is nounphrase_list and the score of Mitchell is 1, Hence the updated score is also 1
- The next phrase in noun phrase list is the first occurrence of `machine learning` has scores `[4, 5]`, Hence the updated scores for `machine` is 9 and `learning` is 9
- The next phrase in noun phrase list is the first occurrence of `software engineering` has scores `[7, 8]`, Hence the updated scores for `software` is 15 and `learning` is 15
- The next phrase in noun phrase list is the first occurrence of `machine learning` has scores `[19, 20]`, Hence the updated scores for `machine` is 39 and `learning` is 39
- The next phrase in noun phrase list is the first occurrence of `deep learning` has scores `[25, 26]`, Hence the updated scores for `machine` is 51 and `learning` is 51

**Note**:

- The words `machine` & `learning` should occur together in same order
- The words `software` & `engineering` should occur together in same order
- The words `machine` & `learning` should occur together in same order
- The words `deep` & `learning` should occur together in same order

Comment: when you say "*The next phrase in noun phrase list is the first occurrence of machine learning has scores [4, 5], Hence the updated scores for machine is 9 and learning is 9*" it's unclear whether you need to have "machine" and "learning" next to each other or if you take the first available "machine" and the first available "learning"

Comment: Yes, they should occur together (and also in same order). Updated the question as well. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is somewhat complicated, but perhaps we should look at it a different way.

Single-word 'noun phrases' are essentially red herrings for this problem. Since their scores don't change, we do not need to worry about them.

So, we only need to look at the two-word noun phrases:

```
for i, word in enumerate(all_tokens[:-1]): #loop through all but last word (remember single-words are red herrings!)
    if (value := word + " " + all_tokens[i+1]) in nounphrase_list: #use walrus operator to remove from the list so no accidental duplicates.
        nounphrase_list.remove(value)
        total = all_scores[i] + all_scores[i+1] #combined score
        all_scores[i] = all_scores[i+1] = total #set score
```

### Result:

`[1, 2, 3, 9, 9, 6, 15, 15, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 39, 39, 21, 22, 23, 24, 51, 51]`

---

### **Time Complexity**

Not the best at calculating this, but I can calculate runtime the old-fashioned way.

Your code (ran `10,000` times): `.2439` seconds.

My code (ran `10,000` times): `.1208` seconds.

---

Your code (ran `100,000` times): `3.352` seconds.

My code (ran `100,000` times): `1.294` seconds.

---

Your code (ran `1,000,000` times): `26.1021` seconds

My code (ran `1,000,000` times): `12.4637` seconds.

---

Note: I used the `timeit` module. Also clearly only works for two-word 'noun phrases'. It's easy to modify for longer phrases, just add an `elif` statement.

---

Hope this helps!